# Computing Topological Index of an Elliptic Operator in Dimension 1

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I was wondering if there is an easy way to compute the topological index (in the sense of Atiyah-Singer) of a (Fredholm) elliptic operator on a Riemann surface. I'm aware the Todd class is very simple in dimension 1, but I'm not sure how to compute the Chern class of such an operator.

Is there a reasonable way to do this in general? If not, I am particularly interested in working it out for the Laplacian operator, is there a reference where that is done?

Comment: A reference that might be relevant: Michael Taylor's Partial Differential Equations, Volume II, Chapter 10 (Dirac Operators and Index Theory), especially Section 10 (Direct Attack in 2-D). Taylor's PDE series, published by Springer, is available electronically for free through some universities' libraries, so you might check your institution's library.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that book!